# R - Paste command to call a matrix name

Tags: r, string, loops, paste, assign

I have the following commands for one specified country, here AT and I would like to do it for more.

```
c1<-grep(pattern="AT",x=names(climatebig3),value=TRUE)
c1matAT<-climatebig3[c1]
c1matAT<-c1matAT[,which(apply(!is.na(c1matAT[1:27,]),2,all))]
```

Taking a vector of countries and looping it over the first two commands works, but not for the third one.

```
countries<-c("AT","BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK")


for (i in 1:28){assign(paste("c1mat",as.character(countries[[i]]),sep=""),climatebig3[,grep(pattern=as.character(countries[[i]]),x=names(climatebig3),value=TRUE)])

assign(paste("c1mat",as.character(countries[[i]]),sep="", paste("c1mat",as.character(countries[[i]]),sep="")[,which(apply(!is.na(as.character(paste("c1mat",as.character(countries[[i]]),sep=""))[1:27,]),2,all))])}
```

For some reason, the paste command just invokes the name of the matrix and does not recognize it as a matrix in the last line of the code. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't (ever) use `assign`. Use lists instead:

```
#Create an empty named list the same length as the number of countries
c1mat_list <- setNames(vector("list",length(countires)),countries)

#Loop through countries and populate the list
for (x in countries){
  c1 <- grep(pattern= x,x=names(climatebig3),value=TRUE)
  c1mat_list[[x]] <-climatebig3[c1]
  #etc.
}
```